Add unique data to JavaScript map
I have code like this:
for (const item of items) {
  myMap[`${item.id}`] = {
    valueA: item.A,
    valueB: item.B,
    valueC: item.C,
    valueD: item.D
  };
}

This is creating output like:
   "1234": {
        "valueA": "A",
        "valueB": "B",
        "valueC": "C",
        "valueD": "D"
    },
    "5678": {
        "valueA": "E",
        "valueB": "F",
        "valueC": "G",
        "valueD": "H"
    },    
    "9876": {
        "valueA": "A",
        "valueB": "B",
        "valueC": "C",
        "valueD": "D"
    }

The id is changing but the contents of the object within the map are the same.  How can I amend this so a value only gets added to the map collection if the entire contents of the map are unique.  So in my example data above the item with id 9876 would not get added too myMap because the values are already present with id 1234

what would happen if 9876 had something like 'M' for item.D

I think you need to include the original contents of items.

You could convert each object to a string using JSON.stringify, which can serve to identify objects that have the same key/value pairs. Use those keys to build an object, and then take the values of those objects:


const items = [ { id: 1234, A: "A", B: "B", C: "C", D: "D" }, { id: 5678, A: "E", B: "F", C: "G", D: "H" }, { id: 9876, A: "A", B: "B", C: "C", D: "D" } ]

const collected = {};
for (const {id, A, B, C, D} of items) {
    const obj = { valueA: A, valueB: B, valueC: C, valueD: D };
    collected[JSON.stringify(obj)] ??= [id, obj];
}
const map = Object.fromEntries(Object.values(collected));
console.log(map)




I've never seen Object.fromEntries(Object.values(…)) before - but it totally makes sense here!

collected[JSON.stringify(obj)] ??= [id, obj]; can you explain this line of code?

@Ctrl_Alt_Defeat it is modern way of initializing if doesnt exists, collected[JSON.stringify(obj)] = collected[JSON.stringify(obj)] || [id, obj]
